# Build OpenWRT for Dlink DIR-600 b2

Tags: openwrt

I'm trying to build openwrt for my dlink dir-500 rev b2 router.
Here is the wiki page of this router:
http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/d-link/dir-300revb

But in the whole menuconfig I can't find any entry to build for this router.
I selected the following things:

- Target System: Ralink RT288x/RT3xxx
- Subtarget: RT3x5x/RT5350 based boards

I also tried different combinations but I couldn't find my router. The wiki page says the target is ramips. But this target isn't available, too.
I checked out the latest trunk of openwrt.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just want to blindly follow the procedure.
I don't know you are doing this professionally or for hobby.
but in either case just don't rely on documentation try and find things on your own which you can.

To answer your question there is no entry of your board in profile files 
present in "/target/linux/ramips/rt305x/profiles/dlink.mk"
I hope you can add this profile similar to DIR-615 H1.